# connecting to cors enabled api with jquery

Tags: jquery, cors

I'm trying to connect (from localhost) to the wallabee api(which is cors enabled).But i keep logging the failure and no error.Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",

    url: 'http://api.wallab.ee/achievements',
    headers: {
        "X-WallaBee-API-Key":"53c526cc-3770-4255-a082-1ee80ad14847",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:": "*"
},
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },

    success: function(data) {
        console.log('success');
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log("failure");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things here:

1. You cannot set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers in the ajax request. That header is returned by the server in the response to allow cross domain access.
2. The wallabee API does not seem to be CORS enable in your case. Its not returning any of the CORS headers in the pre-flight OPTIONS request. Maybe you need to ask for it?

Comment: I removed the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" (my mistake). And after contacting the wallabee admin he enabled Cors. But it's still not working.

Comment: i solved it by using a php proxy script, something like this [link] (http://benalman.com/code/projects/php-simple-proxy/docs/files/ba-simple-proxy-php.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue with the wallabee api and I've been searching for a few hours.
Turns out, the issue isn't the api but Chrome.

What fixed it for me was launching chrome without web security. For some reason chrome (and firefox) doesn't play nice with cors + localhost. Don't ask me for a detailed explanation though.

- Windows: Add --disable-web-security at the end of your chrome shortcut's target.
- OSX: open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the launch without web security isn't working either
neither on an online webserver